# MyInterface with MyImplementation in separate files of a library

Tags: go, interface

The project structure requires to define interface and implementations in separate files.

It's best to download a small isolated test case to get a picture, but here's the code too. It's a library project that's why `mylib` is declared as package for each file. I wanted to have subpackages but golang doesn't allow that, so instead I put everything under one package while files are in separate directories.

[Download Test Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1irkqdt0qyrndtj/Interfaces.zip?dl=0)

**src/interfaces/my_interface.go**

```
package mylib

type MyInterface interface {
    foo()
    bar()
}
```

**src/interfaces/my_implementation.go** how to import interface here?

```
package mylib

type MyImplementation struct {}

// possible to declare *MyInteface here?
func (imp *MyImplementation) foo() {} 

func (imp *MyImplementation) bar() {}
```

**test/implementations/implementation_test.go**

```
package implementations

import (
    "testing"
    "fmt"
    "implementations"
    mylib2 "interfaces"  // why mylib2 here?
)

func TestImplementation(t *testing.T) {

    // how to declare variable of type `MyInterface` and assign an object `MyImplementation` to it
    interface_type_var := mylib2.MyInterface() // error
    interface_type_var := mylib.MyImplementation{} // error

    fmt.Println("Test successful")
}
```

Question

1. How can I declare a type of MyInterface and assign object of MyImplementation to it.
2. how to import and interface in the implementation file
3. Autocomplete of IDE put this under imports automatically as I was importing interface type. not sure why. `mylib2 "interfaces"`. i learned it's an alias but why do we need alias here?
4. Help fix the code in the `implementation_test` please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have already declared a type of `MyInterface` inside `src/interfaces/my_interface.go`. You don't have to redeclare it and you don't have to explicitly assign `MyImplementation` to the interface. All you have to make sure is that your `MyImplementation` implements all the methods from the interface. As long as both files are in the same package and same folder level, your implementation automatically becomes your interface.
2. As long they are both in the same package and folder you do not have to import interface inside implementation
3. At time of this writing Gogland is in Early Access Program which is just another name for BETA :). I don't think SO allows commenting on anything in beta. Sorry.

**EDIT**

4. Based on the structure of your code, you are taking bit wrong approach when trying to use subfolders. If you are using subfolders, those subfolders should be independent packages. So let's say your GOPATH is `~/go`. You need a structure like this: `~/go/src/github.com/user/mylib`. So if you want a subfolder/subpackage you would have something like this `~/go/src/github.com/user/mylib/util` and util would be its own package. It's wrong to try to have Implementations in one folder and interfaces in another. Rather group them logically and create subpackages. Then in your test you can use them like this:

---

```
import(
  "github.com/user/mylib"
  "github.com/user/mylib/util"
)
```

github.com or any other repo service is important specially if you are writing library that is suppose to be reusable in any project.

Besides that, I'd suggest to use more stable IDE or editor.

Hope this helps

Comment: hi, thanks for the explanation, can you please fix the code as well for the `TestImplementation` also which IDE do you suggest? You may download the test project (link in my question) to see the errors

Comment: sorry I added #4 to the list, appreciate a possible solution, thanks again

Comment: Don't have a suggestion for IDE. I use vim with govim plugin that does everything i need. Maybe you could try Visual Studio Code from Microsoft. I have a friend using that for go and he's happy with it.  Also needs a go package installed.

Comment: it worked, I've given each file in a subfoler, the package name after the folder they are residing, the imports are clean now. I've another question about implementing observer pattern, I'm not really happy with channel based approaches out there, will ping you tomorrow in case if it doesn't work. Thanks again.